# "do not backup" extended attribute in iOS 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios

My application downloads a database file from the internet server at first launch and then may redownload it if the server have a newer version of database. 
This database file is stored in `<Application_Home>/Documents`  directory.

Apple approved previous version of my app when there was no iOS 5.0.1 yet one year ago. 
But now they rejected new version of my app becouse it does not satisfy the rules of data storage.

I read [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011342) on Apple site. But I can't understand is it enough just set `do not back up` attribute to database file and keep the file in `<Application_Home>/Documents` or it's need to place it to another place?
And how to support for previous iOS versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the exact same situation about a month ago with a client's app. It was sufficient to just set the flag on the downloaded file(s) and resubmit. The process is quite straight forward using the Tech Note in the article you linked to.

As always with app reviews, your mileage may vary.

Comment: David, thanks for your post, after applying that function to set "Do not backup" to directory in my case, Do you know how can I check whether that flag is set to my directory or not? using anywhere in file system i guess?

Comment: @JayVachhani the short answer is use get `getxattr`. The documentation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getxattr.2.html) at Apple. The documentation is straightforward and usage is similar to `setxattr`.

Comment: Yes, it was actually sufficient to just set the flag on the my downloaded file and resubmit application. Apple approved it.